# What is the easiest way to add a page to ask for a string in NSIS using MUI?

Tags: nsis, nsis-mui

I'm an NSIS novice.

I'm using the NSIS editor, and the built-in wizard to create a basic installer. I've figured out how to add a second page to ask the user for an alternate folder (install path vs data storage path). I also need to ask them for a URL (a SOAP/WSDL location), and I'd like to just add in another page similar to the directory page that just asks for a generic string (no browse, etc).

I'm using MUI (not MUI2).

Is there some simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

To create a custom page, use nsDialogs (or the older InstallOptions) They are both included in the official installer, go look at some of the examples.